# Save Image to File with Unirest in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, unirest

I am trying to download image using Unirest but the image corrupted after I save it

```js
const downloadChapterPage = async (url, pageName) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        unirest.get(url)
            .end(async (res) => {
                if (res.error) {
                    console.log("Error when downloading page : " + pageName, " ", res.error)
                    resolve();
                }
                fs.writeFileSync(pageName + '.jpg', res.raw_body);
                resolve();
            });
    });
}

downloadChapterPage('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 'page1');
```

also I sued this way but It not work also

```js
const downloadChapterPage = async (url, pageName) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        unirest.get(url)
            .end(async (res) => {
                if (res.error) {
                    console.log("Error when downloading page : " + pageName, " ", res.error)
                    resolve();
                }
                const data = Buffer.from(res.raw_body);
                fs.writeFileSync(pageName + '.jpg', data, 'binary');
                resolve();
            });
    });
}
downloadChapterPage('https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png', 'page1');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- I thought that the encode might be the reason of your issue. So please add `encoding(null)` to the request.
- The mimeType of this image `https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png` is `image/png`.

#### Modified script:

```
const downloadChapterPage = async (url, pageName) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        unirest.get(url)
            .encoding(null) // Added
            .end(async (res) => {
                if (res.error) {
                    console.log("Error when downloading page : " + pageName, " ", res.error)
                    resolve();
                }
                const data = Buffer.from(res.raw_body);
                fs.writeFileSync(pageName + '.png', data, 'binary'); // Modified or fs.writeFileSync(pageName + '.png', data);
                resolve();
            });
    });
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Unirest](http://unirest.io/nodejs.html)

Comment: @Suhaib Abu shawesh Welcome. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you for replying.